# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'GaitDataset' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm using PyTorch Lightning and PyTorch for LSTM classification. Whenever I train the model, this error shows:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hisha\anaconda3\envs\FYP\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\hisha\anaconda3\envs\FYP\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'GaitDataset' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I'm implementing time series classification using sequences. The original model and data module code is below:

```
class GaitDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, sequences):
        self.sequences = sequences

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.sequences)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sequence, label = self.sequences[idx]
        return dict(
            sequence=torch.Tensor(sequence.to_numpy()),
            label=torch.tensor(label).long()
        )

class GaitDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, train_sequences, test_sequences, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.train_sequences = train_sequences
        self.test_sequences = test_sequences
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def setup(self, stage=None):
        self.train_dataset = GaitDataset(self.train_sequences)
        self.test_dataset = GaitDataset(self.test_sequences)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.train_dataset,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            shuffle=True,
            num_workers=cpu_count()
        )

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.test_dataset,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            shuffle=False,
            num_workers=cpu_count()
        )

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
            self.test_dataset,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            shuffle=False,
            num_workers=2
        )


N_EPOCHS = 250
BATCH_SIZE = 64

data_module = GaitDataModule(train_sequences, test_sequences, BATCH_SIZE)


class SequenceModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features, n_classes, n_hidden=256, n_layers=3):
        super().__init__()

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=n_features,
            hidden_size=n_hidden,
            num_layers=n_layers,
            batch_first=True,
            dropout=0.5
        )
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.lstm.flatten_parameters()
        _, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(x)

        out = hidden[-1]
        return self.classifier(out)


class GaitPredictor(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, n_features: int, n_classes: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = SequenceModel(n_features, n_classes)
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def forward(self, x, labels=None):
        output = self.model(x)
        loss = 0
        if labels is not None:
            loss = self.criterion(output, labels)
        return loss, output

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        sequences = batch['sequence']
        labels = batch['label']
        loss, outputs = self(sequences, labels)
        predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
        step_accuracy = accuracy(predictions, labels)

        self.log('train_loss', loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        self.log('train_accuracy', step_accuracy, prog_bar=True, logger=True)

        return {'loss': loss, 'accuracy': step_accuracy}

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        sequences = batch['sequence']
        labels = batch['label']
        loss, outputs = self(sequences, labels)
        predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
        step_accuracy = accuracy(predictions, labels)

        self.log('val_loss', loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        self.log('val_accuracy', step_accuracy, prog_bar=True, logger=True)

        return {'loss': loss, 'accuracy': step_accuracy}

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        sequences = batch['sequence']
        labels = batch['label']
        loss, outputs = self(sequences, labels)
        predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
        step_accuracy = accuracy(predictions, labels)

        self.log('test_loss', loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        self.log('test_accuracy', step_accuracy, prog_bar=True, logger=True)

        return {'loss': loss, 'accuracy': step_accuracy}

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.0001)


model = GaitPredictor(
    n_features=len(FeatureColumns),
    n_classes=len(label_encoder.classes_)
)

checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath='checkpoints',
    filename='best-checkpoint',
    save_top_k=1,
    verbose=True,
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min'
)

logger = TensorBoardLogger('lightning_logs', name='Gait')

trainer = pl.Trainer(
    checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
    logger=logger,
    max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
    gpus=1,
    progress_bar_refresh_rate=30
)

trainer.fit(model, data_module)
```

How to fix this error? I am using GaitDataset class which describes gait sequences for training, but it seems that Python is unable to import the class properly.

I followed this tutorial from YouTube:
https://youtu.be/PCgrgHgy26c

**Environment:**

- python 3.9.7
- pytorch 1.11.0
- pytorch-lightning 1.5.10

Conda environment configured in Pycharm

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to lightning trying to load the data from the file. It cannot determine the 'GaitDataset'. I guess this is actually a bug in lightning since it should use the fully qualified name to resolve it.

Funny enough you can import it in your main file and it will be found.
Add

```
from your.package.here import GaitDataset
```

It gets funny if you have other wrapper logic happening.

Edit: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68279928/1615430 for the cause of this error